# Using ST_Extrude in PostgreSQL with PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, sfcgal

I'm trying to use the function ST_Extrude() in Postgres 9.2. I enabled the PostGIS 2.2.0 extension and the PostGIS_SFCGAL extension (which carries the ST_Extrude function).

I can see the function in my list of functions (see snapshot), but I cannot use it.

[image: Snapshot from PgAdmin]

When I try following SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE house AS
SELECT id, ST_Extrude(geog, 0, 0, 5) as geom
FROM houses
WHERE id = 1500;
```

I get an error that the function ST_Extrude does not exist:

[image: Error Message:]

Does someone know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ST_Extrude is only supported for geometry type.  From the error looks like you are trying to use it for geography.  You'll probably also want to maybe change your projection to a meter based one to make sense when you extrude.

Try something like :

```
CREATE TABLE house AS
  SELECT id, 
      ST_Extrude(ST_Transform(geog::geometry,900913), 0, 0, 5) as geom
  FROM houses
  WHERE id = 1500;
```